# How to determine the map $\sigma$ in the formula $\int_{\sigma( \Delta )} \omega =\int_{\Delta } \sigma^* \omega $?

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-forms

I wish to compute integrals by using the formula $$\int_{\sigma( \Delta )} \omega =\int_{\Delta } \sigma^* \omega $$ however I can't find a way to determine the map $\sigma$.

For example, suppose I want to compute the integral $$\int_D dx \wedge dy$$
where $D$ is the area between the line $y=x^2$ and $y=x$.
By the above formula I have $$\int_{\sigma ([0,1]\times [0,1])} dx \wedge dy =\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sigma^* (dx \wedge dy) .$$
What should the map $\sigma$ be?

How can I determine it?

Comment: Write down a parametrization of your region. I think the letter $C$ usually suggests a curve, so perhaps a $D$ or $R$ would be less confusing.

Comment: How can I parametrize a region? I can parametrize the two curves easily by $(t,t)$ and $(t,t^2)$ but how do I do this for the region enclosed by the two curves?

Comment: Hint: If $s,t$ are coordinates on the square, map $t=0$ to $y=x^2$ and $t=1$ to $y=x$. It will be best to set it up with $s$ varying corresponding to $x$ varying.

Comment: Is there a general approach? Here, in my example, I have only two curves and I am in $\mathbb{R}^2$. My question was not for this specific example but a more general one. How would this generalize to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and for regions enclosed by an arbitrary number of manifolds?

Comment: Why don’t you finish this one and learn from it? In practice, you do these computations more as you learned in multivariable calculus when it’s a region on $\Bbb R^n$. This parametric definition is needed for integrating over submanifolds, not regions.

Comment: So is it $\sigma (t,s) =(s(1-t)+st,s^2(1-t)+st)$?

Comment: Of course, the first coordinate is just $s$. Yes, that works fine.